# Distributing packages with Apache Thrift

Tags: python, thrift, software-distribution

I'm working on a Python package that uses Thrift. I've never used setuptools/pip but really want to.
I'm just wondering what would be the best way to distribute the generated code?
Right now, my code uses the

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../thrift/gen-py') # Relative directory :(
```

hack to be able to access the generated code in the gen-py directory, but I need on ideas on how clients could use my Thrift generated API easily.

Comment: I guess "use ZIP or the copy command" is not what you are looking for. Could you enhance the question a bit? I have somehow trouble to grasp the real problem you are facing. Why can't you just copy the files? What is so bad about the relative path? Regarding "*I need on ideas on how clients could use my Thrift generated API*", the typical way for API users is to provide the IDL file and have the people generate the code on their own. Thrift is about cross-platform, cross-language RPC. It is simply not feasible to provide generated code for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you need the thrift generated python code to be used by python projects other than the one you are using,

What has worked well for me is create a [source distribution](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/sourcedist.html). There are a few advantages using it.

1. You could version the generated code and distribute it
2. you could add a wrapper module to the modules/packages generated at gen-py and the clients do not need to bother about the internals of thrift (TExceptions etc)
3. The source can be installed via `pip install your-thrift-lib.tar.gz` and need not reside with your project.

https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html is the best place to look to figure out how to create python packages